# Microsoft add-in doesn't work in excel desktop

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, microsoft-edge

I Have an add-in that is working on Excel in chrome, excel in Edge, but doesn't work in excel desktop.

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: For your side question you can see all the versions here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: does it gives an error or something?

Comment: no erros ...amitklein

Comment: i had already checked on the link you provide and, for my windows and office versions it is edge... but... my addin wasn't working on my edge until I've update it manually from Microsoft website so now on my pc i have the latest version of edge, that runs on chromium(on this edge the addin works, but on the old edge no). so it looks to me that excel is still using the old version of edge... that is my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#chromium-based-edge-is-installed-on-my-development-computer-but-my-add-in-does-not-use-it) amitklein gave, it says:

> Office will still use the EdgeHTML base for add-ins until a build of Office 365 that supports Chromium is installed on the computer. We expect these builds to ship in 2020. They will likely appear in the Insiders channel in the first half of the year.

I haven't found the Chromium based Office 365 in insider channel so I think the version for now is still EdgeHTML based and Excel uses Edge Legacy.

Comment: Thanks.. I haven't read all the final notes on the link! That's not good for me! Do we have any eta for this change?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that. Let's see. It says the first half of the year. But maybe it will be delayed by the outbreak of COVID-19.